# How to make sure we are always Intercepting "Send to My Favorites" user actions

Tags: cme, gui-extensions

I have recently implemented a [rename favorites feature for Tridion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037820/tridion-favorites-ability-to-rename-favorite-links) and in the process I am intercepting the `AddUri` command and posing a prompt for the user to provide a new name for the favorite.

While testing the feature we have found the AddUri command is sometimes not called for the "Send to My Favorites" click, at least our prompt wasn't showing up in some cases.

For example: I added a page to favorites, my prompt showed up and I gave it a new name. Then I deleted it from the favorites. Then I added the page again to the favorites. This time my prompt for a new name did not show up.

Is there a different command or cache that I need to look at? For now I am refreshing the whole page after every delete of a favorite....

Here is command extension code for AddURI interception:

```
    <cfg:group name="NewNameFavorites.CommandSet" merge="always"        merger="Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Configuration.Resources.CommandGroupProcessor">
    <cfg:fileset>
      <cfg:file type="script">/NewNameFavorites/NewNameFavorites.js</cfg:file>
      <cfg:file type="reference">NewNameFavorites.Interface</cfg:file>
    </cfg:fileset>
    <cfg:dependencies>
      <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
      <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
    </cfg:dependencies>
   </cfg:group>

    <ext:commandextensions>
      <ext:commands>
        <ext:command name="AddUri" extendingcommand="NewNameFavorites"/>
      </ext:commands>
      <ext:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>NewNameFavorites.CommandSet</cfg:dependency>
      </ext:dependencies>
    </ext:commandextensions>

 <cfg:commandset id="NewNameFavorites.Interface">
     <cfg:command name="NewNameFavorites" implementation="Commands.NewNameFavorites"      />
  </cfg:commandset>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
Type.registerNamespace("Commands");

Commands.NewNameFavorites= function NewNameFavorites() {
    Type.enableInterface(this, "Commands.NewNameFavorites");
    this.addInterface("Tridion.Cme.Command", ["NewNameFavorites"]);
};

Commands.NewNameFavorites.prototype._isAvailable = function NewNameFavorites$_isAvailable(selection, pipeline) {
    console.debug("Favorites Is Available called");
    if (pipeline)
        pipeline.stop = false;
    return $cme.getCommand("AddUri")._isAvailable(selection, pipeline);
};

FavoritesReload = function (event) {
    $models.$cme.getShortcuts().getList().unload();
};

Commands.NewNameFavorites.prototype._isEnabled = function NewNameFavorites$_isEnabled(selection, pipeline) {
    console.debug("Favorites Is Enabled called");
    if (pipeline)
        pipeline.stop = false;
    try {
        var view = $display.getView();
        var list = view.getListObject("cme:shortcuts");
        list.removeEventListener("itemadd", FavoritesReload);
        list.removeEventListener("itemupdate", FavoritesReload);

        list.addEventListener("itemadd", FavoritesReload);
        list.addEventListener("itemupdate", FavoritesReload);

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.debug("Favorites Reload Error occured: " + err);
    }
    return $cme.getCommand("AddUri")._isEnabled(selection, pipeline);
};

Commands.NewNameFavorites.prototype._execute = function NewNameFavorites$_execute(selection, pipeline) {
    console.debug("Favorites Execute called");
    if (pipeline)
        pipeline.stop = false;

    $cme.getCommand("AddUri")._execute(selection, pipeline);

    var arrItems = [];
    //selectedItem = selection.getItems()[0];
    var itemsProcessed = 0;
    var items = Array.clone(selection.getItems());
    var itemsLen = items.length;

    var addFavoritesCustomTitle = function (event) {
        var username = Tridion.ContentManager.UserSettings.getInstance().getUserName();//Tridion.UI.UserSettings.getJsonUserSettings(true).User["@ID"];
        username = username.replace('\\', '\\\\');
        var customTitles = JSON.stringify(arrItems);
        var serviceURL = "/ManageAppData.svc/AddFavoritesCustomTitles";
        var favoriteData = '{"username" : "' + username + '","customTitles" : ' + customTitles + '}'; //
        $j.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: favoriteData,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            url: serviceURL,
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
            $models.$cme.getShortcuts().getList().unload();
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error Renaming Favoties!');
        }
    });
};

var itemLoad = function (event) {
    var item = this;
    var itemId, itemTitle;
    $evt.removeEventHandler(item, "load", itemLoad);
    itemId = item.getId();
    itemTitle = item.getTitle();
    var newTitle = prompt("Enter Title for the Favorite", itemTitle);
    newTitle = newTitle.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-_\s]/g, '');
    newTitle = newTitle.trim();
    if (!newTitle) newTitle = itemTitle;

    if (newTitle != itemTitle) {
        if (item && Type.isFunction(item.getTCMItemId)) {
            if (refId = item.getTCMItemId()) {
                itemId = refId;
            }
        }
        newTitle = newTitle.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9-_\s]/g, '');
        arrItems.push({ "itemId": itemId, "newTitle": newTitle });
    }
    itemsProcessed++;
    if (itemsLen == itemsProcessed) addFavoritesCustomTitle();
};

for (var i = 0; i < itemsLen; i++) {
    var item = $models.getItem(items[i]);
    $evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", itemLoad);
    item.load();
}

};
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a code of `interception`? 
Are you doing `interception` throught command extension?

Comment: yes UI Beardcore, I am using command extension....

Comment: Hi Ram,   Might be worth adding your js code to your question and let us know if you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Will get back to you later today with a working demo. :)

Comment: Yes, basically the interesting part is the JS implementation.
As it seems like pipeline processing is not going into your command.

Comment: Hi guys, Inaie code didnt fix the problem, I have added my JS code to the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume the problem is in

```
$evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", itemLoad);
item.load();
```

As if Item is loaded, then it won`t fire load event on`item.load()`.

you can either do reload: `item.load(true)` or check if item is loaded

```
if (item.isLoaded())
{
    itemLoad();
}
else
{
    $evt.addEventHandler(item, "load", itemLoad);
    item.load();
}
```

Comment: UI Beardcore, that was it... It fixed the issue perfectly

Comment: any chance you'll share the full solution?

Answer (score 11):

As I've promised, I'm back with a skeleton Visual Studio 2010 project that demonstrates a few concepts:

- a possible structure of a CME Extension Editor within a Visual Studio project
- editor's configuration to be able to extend the functionality provided by CME Dashboard, as of now (pre 2013 release)
- and so far, two ways to extend an existing CME command -- e.g. Tridion.Cme.Commands.AddUri, by sub-classing it or by using the command extensions.

Source code is publicly available on github:
https://github.com/lnaie/CmeExtEditor

I hope this helps,
Lucian

Comment: Hey Inaie, thanks for the code. But it didnt fix the problem... I have addded my JS code to my question.

Comment: POC should fix the issue with your command not being called every time user uses "Send to My Favorites". The actual implementation of the command it's also important... but have fun! :)